# Jhipster - Installation issues with latest version

Tags: java, node.js, maven, npm, jhipster

I have a problem working with jhipster
My installation of java, and node worked fine.
Also installed the hipster fine. Now when I work on a project. I see a npm error
I have attached the log file

```
0 verbose cli C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js
1 info using npm@8.15.0
2 info using node@v16.17.0
3 timing npm:load:whichnode Completed in 0ms
4 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 2ms
5 timing config:load:file:C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\npmrc Completed in 2ms
6 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 3ms
7 timing config:load:cli Completed in 2ms
8 timing config:load:env Completed in 1ms
9 timing config:load:file:C:\Projects\jhip1\cplan\.npmrc Completed in 1ms
10 timing config:load:project Completed in 3ms
11 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\MyPC\.npmrc Completed in 0ms
12 timing config:load:user Completed in 1ms
13 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\MyPC\AppData\Roaming\npm\etc\npmrc Completed in 0ms
14 timing config:load:global Completed in 0ms
15 timing config:load:validate Completed in 1ms
16 timing config:load:credentials Completed in 1ms
17 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 1ms
18 timing config:load Completed in 15ms
19 timing npm:load:configload Completed in 15ms
20 timing npm:load:mkdirpcache Completed in 1ms
21 timing npm:load:mkdirplogs Completed in 0ms
22 verbose title npm run clean-www
23 verbose argv "run" "clean-www"
24 timing npm:load:setTitle Completed in 2ms
25 timing config:load:flatten Completed in 3ms
26 timing npm:load:display Completed in 5ms
27 verbose logfile logs-max:10 dir:C:\Users\MyPC\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs
28 verbose logfile C:\Users\MyPC\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-08-31T00_33_10_177Z-debug-0.log
29 timing npm:load:logFile Completed in 8ms
30 timing npm:load:timers Completed in 1ms
31 timing npm:load:configScope Completed in 0ms
32 timing npm:load Completed in 33ms
33 silly logfile start cleaning logs, removing 2 files
34 timing command:run Completed in 20ms
35 verbose stack Error: spawn bash ENOENT
35 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:283:19)
35 verbose stack     at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:478:16)
35 verbose stack     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
36 verbose pkgid cplan@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
37 verbose cwd C:\Projects\jhip1\cplan
38 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19043
39 verbose node v16.17.0
40 verbose npm  v8.15.0
41 error code ENOENT
42 error syscall spawn bash
43 error path C:\Projects\jhip1\cplan
44 error errno -4058
45 error enoent spawn bash ENOENT
46 error enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
46 error enoent
47 verbose exit -4058
48 timing npm Completed in 78ms
49 verbose code -4058
50 error A complete log of this run can be found in:
50 error     C:\Users\MyPC\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-08-31T00_33_10_177Z-debug-0.log
```

These are my env setting, which I see mismatched when I look at the log and what I don't understand is why node is installed again, when I already have it in my machine

```
C:\Projects\jhip1\cplan>where mvn
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).

C:\Projects\jhip1\cplan>where npm
C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm
C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd

C:\Projects\jhip1\cplan>where node
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe

C:\Projects\jhip1\cplan>where java
C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-11.0.16.101-hotspot\bin\java.exe

C:\Projects\jhip1\cplan>echo %JAVA_HOME%
C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-11.0.16.101-hotspot

C:\Projects\jhip1\cplan>
C:\Projects\jhip1\cplan>node -v
v16.17.0

C:\Projects\jhip1\cplan>java -version
openjdk version "11.0.16.1" 2022-08-12
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-11.0.16.1+1 (build 11.0.16.1+1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-11.0.16.1+1 (build 11.0.16.1+1, mixed mode)

C:\Projects\jhip1\cplan>npm --v
8.15.0

C:\Projects\jhip1\cplan>jhipster --version
INFO! Using bundled JHipster
7.9.2
```

I have had this problem fthe or last 8 hours , so I had cleaned the npm cache and manually deleted the directory as well using npm cache clean and manually deleted
C:\Users\MyPC\AppData\Local\npm-cache

I also deleted the following directory to clean it all from
Users/MyPC/.m2/repository

Comment: I have some more details from the CLI Screen

Comment: ERROR! Command failed with exit code 4294963238: npm run clean-www
Error: Command failed with exit code 4294963238: npm run clean-www

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things helped

1. I found I had two jHipster version installed so I removed any local copies of it
2. I removed global hipster and installed the latest version

Both of these steps (or may be the step 2) helped me get rid of  npm run clean-www Error

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue, try removing `.nmprc` file.

See https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/19294

The objective of the local Node installation by [frontend-maven-plugin](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin) is to isolate your build environment from your PC installation, it provides you with build consistency and lets you easily isolate different projects that may require different versions of Node. It makes it easier to build a continuous integration environment that does not require pre-installation of Node.

Comment: Thanks for your response and for pointing me to the right thread. However I still have the same problem. I removed the .nmprc file first from the C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm and started the hipster jdl again but it did not help and I see the same error.  Then later I deleted the .nmprc from the project folder only by deleting the .nmprc file and let all other overwrite .. but I still have the same issue. Please advise

Comment: Please open an issue on github